# Aligning an INPUT and a DIV side by side

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to align a real button and a fake button on a single line. I've been asked to make my link look like a button so I created an image sprite for it. The problem is, I can't get the `input` and the `div` to play nice.

```
    <div class="submitForm">
        <input type="submit" value="Rename" />
        <div class="smallButton">@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "SiteIndex", new { id = @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SiteID) })</div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SiteID)
    </div>
```

Above is the HTML (ASP.net MVC 4) and below is the CSS:

```
.smallButton
{
    display: inline;
}

.smallButton a
{
    color: #000 !important;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    background: url('../../Images/smallBtn.jpg') 0 0;
}

.smallButton a:Hover
{
    color: #000 !important;
    background: url('../../Images/smallBtn.jpg') 0 -26px;
}

.smallButton a:Active
{
    color: #000 !important;
    background: url('../../Images/smallBtn.jpg') 0 -52px;
}
```

I forgot to clarify, I need this to be aligned properly in IE 6 and IE 7. It does look like it should in Chrome.

Comment: IE6? My condolences. I've had the misfortune of having to build websites for IE6, but I managed to explain to my client that they should be glad it functioned at all! Anyway, there's no way you can make this a real button instead of a link that looks like one?

Comment: Yeah, it's brutal but that's what the client wants. The visuals of having it look like an actual button do work fine, it was the alignment that wasn't going my way. I broke down and decided to commit a mortal sin. I used a table.

Comment: Good for you. Tables are the swiss army knife of HTML. I always laugh when I see people struggling to get it right, and to use much more markup than is necessary, just to avoid the use of tables.

Answer (score 1):

- If you use display:inline, you have to use it in both of input and div. Your css only apply display:inline to div.
- Another way of doing it is float:left input field.
- You can also use twitter bootstrap span class.

Comment: I'll have to play around with this a bit more, it's still giving me the same issues. I'd like to do it this way rather than my current fix. A table.

Comment: can u post ur plain html/css code in fiddle. I can quickly fix it for u.